# Make (first) row unselectable in pickerview (Swift 3, Xcode)

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to make the first rows of my picker views unselectable but it isn't working. I've tried the following options but both of them give a few errors or are for **previous Swift versions**.
- [Disable particular row value in UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719508/disable-particular-row-value-in-uipickerview)
- [(iOS) How to make first value in UIPickerView unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659074/ios-how-to-make-first-value-in-uipickerview-unselectable)

My code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return list1.count
    } else {
        return list2.count
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return "\(list1[row])"
    } else {
        return "\(list2[row])"
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        frequency = list1[row]
    } else {
        period = list2[row]
    }
}
```

My arrays:

```
list1 = ["Select", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]
list2 = ["Select", "days", "weeks"]
```

I want to make "Select" unselectable in both pickerviews. Also I want to sent an error if the user doesn't change the pickerview options (tries to continue with "select" selected, even if it is unselectable).

Button code to continue:

```
@IBAction func addActivity(_ sender: Any) {
if (input.text != "" && pickerString != "Select") {
    nameActivity = input.text!
    list.append(nameActivity)
    input.text = ""
} else if (input.text == "") {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
        "Please give the activity a name!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else if pickerString == "Select" {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
        "Select something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do as on links you provided ?
row == 0 in didSelectRow method ? What's wrong with this ?

Comment: If pickerView.selectedrowincomponent != 0 { //do whatever you want to do }

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Should I then just place `if (row == 0) {
        [pickerView selectRow:row+1 inComponent:component animated:YES];
    }` in the already defined 'didSelectRow'? Because this gives me a couple of errors, it wants to place a few commas and finally it says `Expected expression in container literal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Let your first element be "--Select--". Now create a variable of type, store the picker view row value in this string. If the selected row is equal to "--Select--", then create an alert and notify the user to select your options.

OR

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // Check row

    print(row)

    if(row == 0)
    {
       //Create an alert
    }
    else
    {
       // IMPLEMENT_CODE
    }

}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate 
{  

   @IBOutlet var pickerView: [UIPickerView]!

   var pickerString:String = "--Select--"

   var array:[String] = ["--Select--","Apple","Ball","Cat","Dog"]



// number of rows or number of components

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

// number of rows that we have to set

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

// set title in picker view according to the elements

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return array[row]
}

// when an element is selected, store in a string

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    print(row)

    pickerString = array[row]

    print(pickerString)

}
```

Here when you select any row in pickerView, the string is stored in the string and you can also see the row number selected.

You can also add a button, such that on button action if the string has "--Select--" in it, it will show an alert.
OR
Store the row value in an integer variable and on button action, if the integer variable == 0, then create an alert.

UPDATE 2:

```
@IBAction func addActivity(_ sender: Any) {
if (input.text == "") {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
    "Please give the activity a name!",preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} 
else 
if pickerString == "Select" {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
    "Select something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
}
else
{
nameActivity = input.text!
list.append(nameActivity)
input.text = ""
}
}
```

UPDATE 3:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var pickerView: [UIPickerView]!

@IBOutlet var selectAny: UILabel!

var pickerString:String = “—-Select-—“

var array:[String] = ["—-Select-—“,”Apple”,”Ball”,”Cat”,”Dog”]

// number of rows or number of components

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

// number of rows that we have to set

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

// set title in picker view according to the elements

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return array[row]
}

// when an element is selected, store in a string

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    print(row)

    pickerString = array[row]

    print(pickerString)

}

// Button action

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print(pickerString)

    print(length!)

    if(pickerString == “--Select--“){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: “Error”, message: "Please select.”, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else
            if(pickerString != “—-Select—-“){

                yourCode()
    }
}

func yourCode()
  {
     // do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to explain this? Because I don't really get it

Comment: I'm not sure if it works. I now have my button set up to `if input.text != "" && pickerString != "--Select") { continue } else { error}` but it continues anyway? See my updated question for the button code!

Comment: @GBuis Check Update 2.

Comment: Worked somewhat! Since I have 2 pickerviews I changed the code a little bit: `else if pickerString == "Select" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Select something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
        }
        else if picker2String == "Select" { // same code as before }`. The alert is sent if input.text = "", but there is no alert when 'Select' is selected one or both of the picker views? :/

Comment: @deadShot Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work in your case:

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the initial selection of both picker views to the first item, this will prevent the user from proceeding without changing the selections.
    frequencyPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

    periodPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var selectedRow = row

    if selectedRow == 0 {

        selectedRow = 1

        pickerView.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: component, animated: false)
    }

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        frequency = list1[selectedRow]
    } else {
        period = list2[selectedRow]
    }
}
```

In your continue action you could implement something like this:

```
func continue() {

    if frequencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 || periodPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {

        // Alert the user that he needs to pick the correct values.
        return
    }

    // Perform some action to proceed in the application.
}
```

Comment: Works so far for both the pickerviews! Only doesn't solve the problem completely. If the user loads the screen with the pickerviews the user is able to leave the pickers as they are presented to them and if the user doesn't change them and continues, Xcode doesn't see that a row is actually selected and gives the picker view an empty variable.

Comment: Still the same.. in both cases the Pickerview variable is 'Select' when the picker view changes from first row to second one